# Will Ubuntu degrade my macbook pro battery?

Tags: battery, macbook

I used Ubuntu on my previous laptops and it was very common that after I use Ubuntu on my laptop the battery almost always degraded. The batteries on my old laptops were LiON.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu or should I say Linux doesn't degrade batteries, it just puts to use what is already there and uses enough power to run the kernel and software the end-user needs to run...  Power management is always being worked on to make things run better for longer and of course choosing a lighter desktop like XFCE or LXDE will make the battery go farther than eye-candy rich desktops like Unity and KDE...

Comment: You mean the battery charging is done wholly by the hardware, there is no specific software that controls the charging proccess?

Comment: That is correct...

Answer (score 0):

I got MacBook Air 2017 here, powertop + light theme + deactivated bluetooth gives me about 6-7 hours. And yet I'm confident it can be better.